# Can't iterate over csv file after calling list()

Tags: python, python-3.x

When using `list()` to find the line count of the csv file, I am unable to iterate over the csv after.

This is working:

```
with open(data, 'r') as f_csv:
     csv_file = csv.reader(f_csv)
     for row in csv_file:
         print(row)
```

This is not working:

```
with open(data, 'r') as f_csv:
     csv_file = csv.reader(f_csv)
     print(len(list(csv_file)))
     for row in csv_file:
         print(row)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must either create a second reader, seek to the beginning of the iterator with `f_csv.seek(0)`, or read the contents into a variable. Once you call `list()` on it, you are at the end of the reader.

```
with open("sample.csv", "r") as f_csv:
    reader = csv.reader(f_csv)
    data = [row for row in reader]
    print(len(data))
    for row in data:
        print(row)
```

This is an example, and here is example of using `seek`:

```
with open("sample.csv", "r") as f_csv:
    reader = csv.reader(f_csv)
    print(len(list(reader)))
    f_csv.seek(0)
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```

Comment: @fraxton: That is because I led you astray on `seek`. That must be called on the file handle. I have updated my answer with this example too for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

This is because when you call `list(csv_file)`, this exhausts the file and moves the file pointer to the end of file as `csv.reader` returns an iterator that loops over each line until EOF is reached.

Perhaps store `list(csv_file)` in a variable and loop over that, or you can call `f_csv.seek(0)` before the loop to return the file pointer back to the start of the file.

```
with open(data, 'r') as f_csv:
    csv_file = csv.reader(f_csv)
    print(len(list(csv_file)))
    f_csv.seek(0)
    for row in csv_file:
        print(row)
```

Comment: @fraxton you seek the f_csv (the file pointer) not the csv reader